# Customising Trust Pilot Widget

Tags: css

I'd really appreciate help with customising my Trust Pilot widget code... I basically want to resize the widget to 150 pixels and I want to remove the 'selected reviews' bit at the top.

```
 <div class="tp_-_box" data-tp-settings="domainId:3636783,showHeader:False,showDate:False,width:300"><a hidden="" href="http://www.trustpilot.co.uk/review/www.dowsingandreynolds.com" rel="nofollow">Dowsing &amp; Reynolds Reviews</a></div>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
(function(){var a="https:"==document.location.protocol?"https://ssl.trustpilot.com":"http://s.trustpilot.com",b=document.createElement("script");b.type="text/javascript";b.async=true;b.src=a+"/tpelements/tp_elements_all.js";var c=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];c.parentNode.insertBefore(b,c)})();
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The width and no reviews:

```
data-tp-settings="domainId:3636783,showHeader:False,showDate:False,width:150,showReviews:False">
```

If you want to completely customize the output, you can use Javascript to get the data through JSONP, which will return a feed with the reviews, starts, score, etc. See the link below for more info.

To receive data you can use the following URL to retreive JSON:

```
https://ssl.trustpilot.com/tpelements/3636783/f.jsonp
```

jQuery example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://ssl.trustpilot.com/tpelements/3636783/f.jsonp',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp: false,
  jsonpCallback: 'trustpilot_jsonp_callback',
  success: function(data, status) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(XHR, txtStatus, errThrown) {
    console.log('Error: ' + txtStatus);
    console.log('Error: ' + errThrown);
  }
});
```

More info:

1. [Settings page](http://trustpilot.github.io/developers/#trustbox)
2. [JSON Feed](http://trustpilot.github.io/developers/#jsondoc)
3. [JSONP Example](http://trustpilot.github.io/developers/#jsonp)